# Why is my nested grid not showing on screen? CSS

Tags: html, css

`

```css
body {
    
    margin:0;

}

.main-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:#7D7D7D;
}

.header-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:15vh;
    background-color: #9BBB88;
    
    }

.middle-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:75vh;
}

.calculator {
    display:grid;
    grid-template: 
        "a a"
        "b c";    
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

.display-container {
    grid-area: a;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.numbers-container {
    
    grid-template:
    "seven eight nine"
    "four five six"
    "one two three"
    "  zer  ";
    grid-area: b;
    background-color: blue;
}

#seven-btn {
    grid-area: seven;

}

#eight-btn {
    grid-area: eight;
}
#nine-btn {
    grid-area: nine;
}
#four-btn {
    grid-area: four;
}
#five-btn {
    grid-area: five;
}
#six-btn {
    grid-area: six;
}
#one-btn {
    grid-area: one;
}
#two-btn {
    grid-area: two;
}
#three-btn {
    grid-area: three;
}
#zero-btn {
    grid-area: zer;
}

.functions-container {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.footer-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:10vh;
    background-color:#3B6225; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <header class="header-container">
            <h1 id="header-text">Have fun playing with this, a simple calculator.</h1>

        </header>
        <div class="middle-container">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div class="display-container">
                    <p id="display"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="numbers-container">
                    <button id="seven-btn">7</button>
                    <button id="eight-btn">8</button>
                    <button id="nine-btn">9</button>
                    <button id="four-btn">4</button>
                    <button id="five-btn">5</button>
                    <button id="six-btn">6</button>
                    <button id="one-btn">1</button>
                    <button id="two-btn">2</button>
                    <button id="three-btn">3</button>
                    <button id="zero-btn">0</button>
                </div>
                <div class="functions-container">
                    <button id="clr-btn">Clear</button>
                    <button id="div-btn">/</button>
                    <button id="times-btn">x</button>
                    <button id="plus-btn">+</button>
                    <button id="minus-btn">-</button>
                    <button id="equals-btn">=</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer-container">
            <h2 id="footer-text">Keeping it simple.</h2>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="script.js">
</script>

</html>
```

`I'm building a simple calculator in basic HTML/CSS and JS. My goal was to separate the calculator itself into 3 divisions:

1. equation display
2. digit buttons
3. function buttons

The calculator is a grid itself and I'm trying to make the two buttons' display to be set to grid as well. My code for that CSS:

```
.calculator {
    display:grid;
    grid-template: 
        "a a"
        "b c";    
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
.numbers-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    "seven eight nine"
    "four five six"
    "one two three"
    "  zer  ";
    grid-area: b;
    background-color: blue;
}
#seven-btn {
    grid-area: seven;
}
#eight-btn {
    grid-area: eight;
}
#nine-btn {
    grid-area: nine;
} // etc...
```

My issue is that the numbers-container disappears after I add display:grid to its CSS. First image is before adding display:grid to the numbers-container, the second image is after I've added that line. [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBArc.png)   [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkmGI.png)

Comment: Can you please share more code like HTML and JS as well?

Comment: Yes, I just put up the HTML but I haven't started on JS yet, just trying to set up the CSS

Comment: could you maybe setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think you are writing tons of css. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_three_columns